# I keep getting "NoneType object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, exception, csv

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to browse for a CSV file, and then parse that CSV file, before sending off each value to the Google Search API (that bit is already written).

So right now I've got this:

```
def loadtemplate():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("CSV files", "*.csv")
                                                             ,("Text Files", "*.txt")
                                                             ,("All files", "*.*") ))
    if filename: 
            try: 
                csvfile = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',')
                for row in csvfile:
                    for x in row:
                            generate(x)
            except: 
                tkMessageBox.showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file \n'%s'"%filename)
                return
```

And my CSV file looks like this:

```
seo,company name,drupal,wordpress themes,awesome web design
```

Nothing too crazy. Anyway, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/Projects/Google Searcher/realsearcher.py", line 20, in loadtemplate
    generate(x)
  File "C:/Python27/Projects/Google Searcher/realsearcher.py", line 31, in generate
    gs = gs['cursor']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

It seems like somehow a value is being set to None? But I keep either trying to use a conditional where `if x == None:`, it'll not allow the query to go through or try to change the CSV file to where nothing like that should be parsed.

What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

PS - this is what the variable row looks like:

```
['seo', 'company name', 'drupal', 'wordpress themes', 'awesome web design']
```

Here is generate() (I used duplicate code because I felt that writing something that would do both solutions would take longer and was unnecessary because this project won't be expanded):

```
def generate(item):
    infoget = urllib.quote(item)
    infoquote = '"' + infoget + '"' 
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=" + infoget)
    gs = simplejson.load(response)
    gs = gs['responseData']
    gs = gs['cursor']
    gs = gs['estimatedResultCount']
    print gs
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=" + infoquote)
    gs = simplejson.load(response)
    gs = gs['responseData']
    gs = gs['cursor']
    gs = gs['estimatedResultCount']
    print gs
```

Comment: What does the generate function do? Can you show the code for that as well?

Comment: Well, the gs variable is not subscriptable (i.e. it's not a dictionary, or similar data structure). Is the "generate" function from the API, or is it your code?

Comment: the generate function is from my code. I'll post it.

Comment: Is there an empty line in the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be obvious from the traceback that the problem has nothing whatsoever to do with the CSV loading, but comes from the `generate` function. We can see from the code for that function that you're querying the Google Search API (for every item in every line!). However, in various cases, you're getting a blank result back.

You should rewrite the `generate` function to be a little more sensible, without spamming Google (they don't like it), and dealing with failures a sensibly - checking that the nested values exist in the JSON before relying on them.

Comment: Well, the whole idea of the application is to parse Google's search to see what the amount of search results is for a particular keyword phrase.

Comment: How would I get around querying Google frequently?

Comment: Yep, this was it. It was a Google error. After we were discussing everything here (and the Traceback, but I thought that was related to something else possibly), I had started to suspect it.

Comment: So, the question is, is there anyway to parse Google LICITLY? Like is there anyway whatsoever?

Comment: It's probably just about the rate. If you put in some calls to eg `time.sleep(5)` to pause for 5 seconds between calls, you may have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
gs = None
>>> gs = gs['aa']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in -toplevel-
    gs = gs['aa']
TypeError: unsubscriptable object
>>>
```

Somehow variable gs is reinitialise or initialize to `None`

```
gs['responseData'] is None
```

try:

```
gs = simplejson.load(response)
gs = gs and gs ['responseData']
gs = gs and gs['cursor']
gs = gs and gs['estimatedResultCount']
print gs
```

example:

```
gs = None
>>> gs and gs['aa']

>>> print gs
None
```